# MySQL update column with value from second table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to replace a users name in one table with their ID, which needs to be referenced from another table. For example:

I have Table A which looks like:

```
ID  |  Key  |  Value
---------------------
1   |  name |  Bob
2   |  name |  Bob
3   |  name |  John
```

And Table B:

```
ID  |  Name
--------------
1   |  Bob
2   |  Rick
3   |  John
```

I am trying to get Table A to look like:

```
ID  |  Key  |  Value
---------------------
1   |  name |  1
2   |  name |  1
3   |  name |  3
```

How would I build a query in MySQL to do this?

Answer (score 3):

One issue is data types.  It is not wise to store numbers as strings.  But, you can get the values you want doing:

```
update a join
       b
       on a.value = b.name
    set a.value = b.id;
```

Comment: You could always execute an `UPDATE TABLE` afterwards to convert it to an integer. Or add an additional integer column first and then update that with the value from table b instead of the name column.

Comment: The correct statement would be `alter table a modify column value int`, but  you should only do this after verifying that the data is correct.